# Hybridauth library in Codeigniter does not work for facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, hybridauth

I'm trying to implement facebook login in my website using Hybridauth library in codeigniter.

I created an application on facebook and added required info (App Key & Secret Key) in hybridauth config file.

My issue is when i try to login with facebook and allow application on my facebook login, while redirecting on my website i get error as
*"User has cancelled the authentication or the provider refused the connection."*

This is my call back url on facebook -
http://xx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/MY_WEB_FOLDER/index.php/hauth/endpoint?hauth.done=Facebook

Can somebody please help me to resolve my issue and help me to facebook login working ?